# when installing bitnami mongodb-sharded, i got error from PVCs: no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I am trying to install my rancher(RKE) kubernetes cluster bitnami/mongodb-shared . But I couldn't create a valid PV for this helm chart.

The error that I am getting:
no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set

This is the helm chart documentation section about PersistenceVolume: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb-sharded/#persistence

This is the StorageClass and PersistentVolume yamls that I created for this helm chart PVCs':

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ssd-nfs-storage
provisioner: nope
parameters:
  archiveOnDelete: "false"
----------
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv
  labels:
    name: db-nfs
spec:
  storageClassName: ssd-nfs-storage # same storage class as pvc
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  nfs:
    server: 142.251.33.78 # ip addres of nfs server
    path: "/bitnami/mongodb" # path to directory
```

This is the PVC yaml that created by the helm chart:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-06-06T17:50:40Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: shardsvr
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: sam-db
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mongodb-sharded
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/component: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
      f:spec:
        f:accessModes: {}
        f:resources:
          f:requests:
            .: {}
            f:storage: {}
        f:volumeMode: {}
      f:status:
        f:phase: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-06-06T17:50:40Z"
  name: datadir-sam-db-mongodb-sharded-shard1-data-0
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "960381"
  uid: c4313ed9-cc99-42e9-a64f-82bea8196629
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Pending
```

Can you tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving the `bitnami/mongodb-sharded` installation instruction with NFS server on Rancher(v2.5.8).

I have three Centos 8 VM. One NFS server(lets we say 1.1.1.1), two k8s nodes(lets we say 8.8.8.8 and 9.9.9.9) on k8s-cluster, i am using RKE(aka Rancher K8S Engine)

1. We will create a NFS server
2. We will bind the nodes to the NFS server
3. We will add `nfs-subdir-external-provisioner` HELM repository to the Rancher Chart Repositories
4. We will install `nfs-subdir-external-provisioner` via rancher charts
5. We will add `bitnami` HELM repo  to the Rancher Chart Repositories
6. We will install `mongodb-sharded` via Rancher charts

---

1. Create a NFS server

```
# nfs server install
dnf install nfs-utils -y
systemctl start nfs-server.service
systemctl enable nfs-server.service
systemctl status nfs-server.service
# you can verify the version
rpcinfo -p | grep nfs
# nfs deamon config: /etc/nfs.conf
# nfs mount config: /etc/nfsmount.conf
mkdir /mnt/storage
# allows creation from client
# for mongodb-sharded: /mnt/storage
chown -R nobody: /mnt/storage
chmod -R 777 /mnt/storage
# restart service again
systemctl restart nfs-utils.service
# grant access to the client 
vi /etc/exports
/mnt/storage    8.8.8.8(rw,sync,no_all_squash,root_squash)
/mnt/storage    9.9.9.9(rw,sync,no_all_squash,root_squash)
# check exporting
exportfs -arv
exportfs -s
# exporting 8.8.8.8:/mnt/storage
# exporting 9.9.9.9:/mnt/storage
```

---

2. Bind the k8s nodes to the NFS server

```
# nfs client install
dnf install nfs-utils nfs4-acl-tools -y
# see from the client shared folder
showmount -e 1.1.1.1
# create mounting folder for client
mkdir /mnt/cstorage
# mount server folder to the client folder
mount -t nfs 1.1.1.1:/mnt/storage /mnt/cstorage
# check mounted folder vis nfs
mount | grep -i nfs
# mount persistent upon a reboot
vi /etc/fstab
# add following codes
1.1.1.1:/mnt/storage /mnt/cstorage  nfs  defaults  0  0
# all done
```

**Bonus:** Unbind nodes.

```
# un mount and delete from client
umount -f -l /mnt/cstorage
rm -rf /mnt/cstorage
# delete added volume from fstab
vi /etc/fstab
```

---

3. Add nfs-subdir-external-provisioner helm repository

**Helm Repository URL:** `https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/`

- Rancher -->
- Cluster Explorer -->
- Apps & Marketplace
- Chart Repositories -->
- Create -->
- Add url like below [this ccreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQFAa.png) -->
- Save -->

---

4. Install `nfs-subdir-external-provisioner` via Charts

- Rancher -->
- Cluster Explorer -->
- Apps & Marketplace
- Charts -->
- [find nfs-subdir-external-provisioner chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gNLH.png) -->
- Select -->
- Give a name(like nfs-pr) -->
- Select Values YAML -->
- [set path, server ip and StorageClass name(we will use this class name later)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKOvQ.png)  -->
- Install -->

---

5. Add `bitnami` HELM repo to the Rancher Chart Repositories

Bitnami HELM URL: `https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami`

- Rancher -->
- Cluster Explorer -->
- Apps & Marketplace
- Chart Repositories -->
- Create -->
- Add url like step 3's screenshot -->
- Save -->

---

6. Install `mongodb-sharded` via Rancher Charts

- Rancher -->
- Cluster Explorer -->
- Apps & Marketplace
- Charts -->
- Find `mongodb-sharded` -->
- Select -->
- Give a name(my-db) -->
- Select Values YAML -->
- [Add global.storageClassname: nfs-client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpCKF.png)(we set this value step 5) -->
- Install

Answer (score 0):

The chart exposes two parameters that allow you to choose the StorageClass you want to use for your PVC(s) (otherwise it will use the 'default' one):

- `configsvr.persistence.storageClass`
- `shardsvr.persistence.storageClass`

Find more information in the [Parameters section](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb-sharded#parameters) of the README.md

So basically you need to install the chart setting these parameters accordingly.